# ¿Cómo evitar que se envíen más de una vez los datos de una petición?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, backend, networking

Tengo un servicio web de un API REST que carga vídeos a un servidor, los vídeos se carga a *Cloudinary* mediante código de backend. El problema es que después de hacer la petición desde la app cliente, pasados unos segundos se vuelve a recibir la misma petición (cómo si se se hubiera enviado de nuevo desde el mismo cliente).

Ambas peticiones se ejecutan normal (sin problemas), pero después de volver de la petición que ejecuta el SDK de cloudinary para cargar el vídeo de la primera petición, sin importar que haya funcionado o no, no me deja responder al host cliente, y me lanza el error: ***Error: Can't set headers after they are sent***, aunque no se haya respondido nada. Después de unos segundos, el servidor donde está el API responde con una respuesta vacía. Luego de otros segundos, regresa de subir el mismo vídeo de la segunda petición y de nuevo, aunque haya funcionado, no responde correctamente, aunque esta vez ya no me lanza el error anterior.

Las cosas que he intentado es dar más tiempo de vida (TTL) a la petición dandole hasta 1 hora para esperar, pero aún así no funciona.

Mi hipótesis es que se replica la petición porque cuando no se recibe una confirmación de que los paquetes se recibieron a su tiempo debido, se envían paquetes de reemplazo. Por esta razón aumenté el TTL de la petición, pero nada...

Este es el fragmento de código de backend:

```
ctrl.create = function(req, res, next) {
  let tracking = req.api.tracking;
  let video = req.api.video;

  video.save()
 .then(function(result) {
   tracking.push(result);
   res.status(result.status).execute({
     "success": result.success,
     "status": result.status,
     "message": result.message, 
     "data": result.data,
     "type": result.data_type
   });
   return tracking.print();
 })
 .catch(function(result) {
   tracking.push(result);
   res.status(result.status).execute({
     "success": result.success,
     "status": result.status,
     "message": result.message, 
     "data": result.data,
     "type": result.data_type
   });
   return tracking.print();
 });
};
```

Esta es la clase vídeo, igual de backend:

```
class Video {
  constructor(video) {
    this.id = video.id;
    this.course = video.course;
    this.title = video.title;
    this.src = video.src;
    this.active = video.active;
    this.create_at = video.create_at;
    this.update_at = video.update_at;
    this.author = video.author;
  }

  save() {
    let self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      let t = moment();

      //cloudinary implements...
      cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(self.url, {
        "resource_type": "video",
        "eager": {"width": 640}
      }, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          return reject(new Message({
            "status": 500,
            "internal_message": "Error al cargar video a cloudynary.",
            "data": err
          }));
        }

        self.src = result.eager[0].secure_url;
        console.log(result);

        let url = `${conf.host_php}/academy/api/post/createvideo.php`;
        let opt = {
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": JSON.stringify({
            "course": self.course,
            "author": self.author,
            "title": self.title,
            "src": self.src
          })
        };

        request.post(url, opt, function(err, response, body) {
          if(err) {
            return reject(new Message({
              "status": 500,
              "internal_message": "Error al hacer post a " + url,
              "data": err
            }));
          }

          try {
            if(typeof body === "string")
              body = JSON.parse(body);

            return resolve(new Message({
              "status": (body.success) ? (200) : (400),
              "message": body.message,
              "internal_message": "Creación de vídeo.",
              "data": (body.success) ? ({ "id": body.id }) : ({}),
              "data_type": (body.success) ? ("object") : ("null"),
              "time": moment().diff(t)
            }));
          }
          catch(err) {
            return reject(new Message({
              "status": 500,
              "internal_message": err,
              "data": body
            }));
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

En el método *save* lleva a cabo dos peticiones a otros servidores, la carga del vídeo a *Cloudinary* y la petición para guardar el registro en una base de datos que está en un servidor distinto.

Lo siguiente es la pequeña pagina que sirve como cliente para cargar el vídeo usando el API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0;}
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="content">
    <form id ="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/v1/api/video/create">
      <label>Archivo.</label>
      <br>
      <input type="file" name = "myfile">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      let frm = $("#frm");
      frm.on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        let fd = new FormData(); //= new FormData(frm[0]);
        fd.append("video", frm[0][0].files[0]);
        fd.append("title", "titulo de prueba");
        fd.append("course", 14);

        //console.log(fd);
        $.ajaxSetup({
          //global: false,
          type: "POST",
          timeout: 3600000
        });
        $.ajax({
          "crossDomine": true,
          "async": true,
          "headers": {
            "clientapp": "a2802be72bf830cddce84893fb9b89eded0e331d",
            "authorization": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsImlhdCI6MTUyMzIwNjYyMywiZXhwIjoxNTU0NzQyNjIzfQ.mGWM651qAHHRC_lM-LHtGG_iD5tKbzVsHRpWaj-RgVuOYEwcHIl-XH3YX19vb8Q7lQTAZNXoT4StOLmV1qUg2tF83DYLH2mOLHWelNwlfsM3kxyrOSpf9QIWj83Q_XAjUzvoKAD27Bta8CCjqgZrflQjNNofn1a9UaBJ5jOIMokJyZ88i5VeLbBg87Zz4U-QSZgPn_-cPRktVk0H_q5GO2y-0h2I1bcgHY7Zuu0iwtgN-XPhyLPIXlIsMXQfpP4HiJIwVimWHROKVadjvXHwtgxMZr3VB1eS5TzhEtWOxqQ2lQsjmEZnxmTA_9mlwtrCpLGDZCZ1ACMmR0OCS6KQ2Q"
          },
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/v1/api/video/create",
          "type": "POST",
          "data": fd,
          "timeout": 3600000,
          "processData": false,
          "contentType": false, 
          "cache": false
        })
        .done(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
          console.log("Falló.");
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo evitar que se hagan dos peticiones cuando sólo he hecho que se haga una, y cómo corregir las respuestas del API, es decir, que no me lance el error: ***Error: Can't set headers after they are sent***.

Supongo que corrigiendo el error en el que se duplican las peticiones se corregiría el otro. Pero no sé.

Gracias.